# mismach in unique value when we ready single image and multiple image

Tags: python

```
mask_names = glob.glob("./drive/MyDrive/ISBI2016_ISIC_Part3B_Training_Data/*.png")
mask_names.sort()
mask_names_subset = mask_names[0:30]
for mask in mask_names_subset:
  
  mask = skimage.io.imread(mask,as_gray="True")
 
  mask1=resize(mask,(1024,768))
  
  
  mask_list.append(mask1)
  
mask_dataset = numpy.array(mask_list)


numpy.unique(mask_dataset[2])
```

Output:

```
array([0.00000000e+00, 2.62815189e-04, 3.55275472e-04, ...,
       9.99999663e-01, 9.99999843e-01, 1.00000000e+00])
```

But when I am reading single image unique out output is 0 and 255:

```
import skimage.io

# read image
imagetest = skimage.io.imread(fname="./drive/MyDrive/ISBI2016_ISIC_Part3B_Training_Data/ISIC_0000000_Segmentation.png")

numpy.unique(imagetest)
```

```
array([  0, 255], dtype=uint8)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make sure you tag your question with proper labels (programming language, relevant technologies etc). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!